# Java + Eclipse: False possible null pointer dereference?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I'm experiencing a warning in Eclipse regarding a "possible null pointer dereference" but i really don't get why. The warning occurs in the following code snippet in the last line:

```
public void addMessage(Message message) {
   WeakReference<MessagesPanelControl> view = null;
   [...]
   if(view != null && view.get() != null)
     view.get().updateView();
}
```

Because of the check before, i'am totally sure, that `view` can't be null. The Eclipse warning is:

> Bug: Possible null pointer dereference in AC.GUI.MessageHandler.addMessage(Message) due to return value of called methodBug: Possible null pointer dereference in AC.GUI.MessageHandler.addMessage(Message) due to return value of called method

If its not a valid warning, how can i supress it? Even @SuppressWarnings("all") does not work.

Comment: What's in `[...]`? All you're showing now is a *definite* `null` value for `view`.

Comment: @chrylis I think he's trying to tell us that the warning seems to have no sense since he's checking for `view` to be `!= null` before calling `view.get().updateView()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a race condition between your `if` statement and its body:

- You check whether `view` is `null`. It's not.
- You check whether `view.get()` (the weakly-referenced `MessagesPanelControl`) is `null`. It's not. You enter the `if` body.
- The garbage collector decides to clear the value inside `view`.
- You call a method on `view.get()`, which is now `null`.

To prevent this, you need to convert the weak reference into a strong reference like this:

```
if(view != null) {
    MessagesPanelControl mpc = view.get();
    if(mpc != null)
        mpc.updateView();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the race condition, now the problem seems to be so obvious for me :)

Answer (score 7):

You're assuming that just because `view.get()` returns a non-null value the first time, it will return a non-null value the second time. It may not - the target could be removed between the two calls. You could eliminate this with:

```
if (view != null) {
    MessagesPanelControl value = view.get();
    if (value != null) {
        value.updateView();
    }
}
```